# group_by and filter removes too many rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Below is my example, let me explain what I am trying to do, although it is not working as I want it to.

I need to find all instances where there are 2+ unique values in column z on the same date for the same person. However, I need to find where a specific list of values in column z are present.

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- c("Person A","Person A","Person A","Person A","Person A","Person A")
y <- c("2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-20","2022-02-01","2022-02-01","2022-02-01")
z <- c("A","D","A","A","C","B")

df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
df

df %>% 
  group_by(x,y) %>% 
  mutate(unique_z = n_distinct(z)) %>% 
  # ungroup() %>% 
  filter(unique_z > 1,
         z %in% c("C","B"))
```

Below is an image of what I want the output to be, but I cannot figure it out.

Row 1 and 2 should be removed because even though it is 2 unique values of z on the same date for the same person, it does not include "C" or "B".

Row 3 is removed because it is only one unique value for that person and date.

Rows 4, 5, and 6 all should stay because that person, date combination has three unique values of z. Also, "C" and/or "B" occur in these rows. For some reason, row 4 is being removed every time. I to see the other values of z on that person, date combination. I thought grouping and filtering would do this, but it does not seem to the way I am doing it.

[image]

Comment: What happens, if there are two `"B"`s and no `"C"` in `z`?

Comment: You could try `filter(unique_z > 1, sum(z %in% c("C","B")) == 2)`. But this depends on your answer to my previous comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `any` to check for the presence of `c("B", "C")` within each group and not at each row; see below:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(x,y) %>% 
  mutate(unique_z = n_distinct(z)) %>% 
  filter(unique_z > 1,
         any(z %in% c("B","C")))
## any(z %in% c("C")) & any(z %in% c("B"))) 
## use this one instead if you want B and C present at the same time ...
## ... and two B's or two C's are not desired

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
# # Groups:   x, y [1]
#   x        y          z     unique_z
#   <fct>    <fct>      <fct>    <int>
# 1 Person A 2022-02-01 A            3
# 2 Person A 2022-02-01 C            3
# 3 Person A 2022-02-01 B            3
```